Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu displays incorrect characters in languages with diacritical marks
I have tried changing to various fonts in VSCode such as Consolas, Monospace, and many other monospace fonts. In all cases, they display characters incorrectly.
The following text will be used to test the display in VSCode:

Phương pháp sSMC-FCM hồi quy được trình bày ở mục
\ref{sec:ssmc_fcm_regression} và cách thức dự đoán dung lượng Pin từ
phương pháp này (mục
\ref{sec:build_battery_capacity_prediction_model}) sẽ được sử dụng để
thực hiện thử nghiệm dự đoán dung lượng Pin. So sánh với phương pháp
này sẽ là các thuật toán học máy khác lần lượt là CatBoost, LightGBM,
CART, XGBoost, Random Forest và Multi Layer Perceptron.

Here is an example of how VSCode on Ubuntu display Vietnamese characters with Consolas font:

The highlighted words are the ones that are displayed incorrectly. The diacritical marks on these words are misaligned from their correct positions. Below is the same text displayed correctly with Consolas font in Text Editor, the default text editing software on Ubuntu:

I have tried using various fonts, and monospace fonts like Consolas display incorrectly in VSCode. However, when I tried using Times New Roman, VSCode displayed the diacritical marks correctly. Unfortunately, this font does not look very good for writing code. Here is an example of how VSCode on Ubuntu display Vietnamese characters with Consolas font:

How can I fix this issue?

Below is the same text displayed correctly with Consolas font in Text Editor, the default text editing software on Ubuntu You should also post that as text into the question. Having it only as a picture means we can't test the text

I have just added the text used to test the display in VSCode

Report a bug to VS Code and hope they fix it. Meanwhile, try more fonts. I had some success with Noto Mono.

"editor.fontFamily": "'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace" is what I have and it's fine

I have tried the font "'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace" but I can't fix the issue. The Noto Mono font also doesn't solve the problem.
